# Removing header Row VAADIN 7.8.4

Tags: java, join, merge, frameworks, vaadin

I need help with this.

This is my code, which I use to join cells (columns) together. But I need something what I can use to remove this "join". E.G. When I click to the button, I want "merge" the cells, and when I click on the other button I want "unmerge" cells.

```
 HeaderRow row = grid.prependHeaderRow();
    row.join("Black","White").setText("Something");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423636/change-column-name-vaadin-7-8-4), where did you get vaadin 7.8.4 from? The latest 7.x [release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423636/change-column-name-vaadin-7-8-4) I can see is 7.7.10. For this exercise I'll assume it's a typo and use 7.7.4...

---

AFAIK it's not possible to un-merge two cells from a header. However, you can work around this by removing the previous header and adding a new one. You can find below a simple implementation which should get you started:

```java
public class GridWithUnmergedColumnHeaders extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final int INDEX_OF_HEADER = 1;
    private boolean shouldMerge = false;

    public GridWithUnmergedColumnHeaders() {
        // basic grid setup
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
        grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
        container.addContainerProperty("name", String.class, "");
        container.addContainerProperty("surname", String.class, "");
        container.addContainerProperty("age", Integer.class, 0);

        grid.addRow("Some", "One", 20);
        grid.addRow("Someone", "Else", 50);

        grid.addHeaderRowAt(INDEX_OF_HEADER).join("name", "surname").setText("Whatever");

        // button to toggle properties
        Button button = new Button("Toggle header merging", event -> {
            if (shouldMerge) {
                grid.removeHeaderRow(INDEX_OF_HEADER);
                grid.addHeaderRowAt(INDEX_OF_HEADER).join("name", "surname").setText("Whatever");
            } else {
                grid.removeHeaderRow(INDEX_OF_HEADER);
                Grid.HeaderRow headerRow = grid.addHeaderRowAt(INDEX_OF_HEADER);
                headerRow.getCell("name").setText("What");
                headerRow.getCell("surname").setText("Ever");
            }
            shouldMerge = !shouldMerge;
        });

        addComponents(grid, button);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: grid-simulate-header-unmerge]